# Converting string[] to list type<SerialNumber>

Tags: c#, list, model-view-controller, collections

Can't seem to work this out.

I have a student class that has a property access modifier

```
{
    public class SerialNumbers
    {
       public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Now i have made a trip to the database and returned by results from a datatable to a string[]

```
string[] serialArray = dt.Rows.OfType<DataRow>().Select(k => k[1].ToString()).ToArray();
```

which outputs the desired results. Now im trying to save the results to my model via the List so i am trying to convert my string[] to a list of type SerialNumber but i keep getting invalid cast

```
List<SerialNumbers> serial = serialArray.Cast<SerialNumbers>().ToList();
```

[image]

Can anybody tell me why this doesn't work, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That `Cast<T>()` call is essentially `(SerialNumber)item` which fails because your items are strings not serial numbers.

You need a projection from strings which will be like

```
List<SerialNumbers> serial = serialArray.Select(s => new SerialNumbers { SerialNumber = s }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't cast String Array to custom type list with build-in methods. I think the simplest way to do it with foreach loop to populate your custom type list.

```
List<SerialNumbers> serial = new List<SerialNumbers>();
foreach (var item in serialArray)
{
    serial.Add(new SerialNumbers() {SerialNumber = item});
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your SerialNumbers class has no way to parse the string type, simply implement a method `void Parse(string[]);` or `void Parse(string);` in the class and use it.

Comment: That's not going to fix the query.